# Magnetic coupled circuit

Tags: inductor, network, mutual-inductance

I am solving this circuit and according to the dot convension,the j6 ohm and j8 ohm have opposite polarities. Applying kvl to both loops,
I got, *10 = j5I1 - j3I2 + j3I2*
Or, *I1 = -j2* A

But I am stuck in the second loop.

It seems like, I2=0 because the mutual impedance of both the opposite polarity inductors with the j5 ohm inductor is same, j3 ohm. Also no active source is present in second loop. Am I right here with dot convention? Please ensure me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can technically write KVL for the second loop and find that only \$I_2=0\$ satisfies it. I suppose the purpose of this task is to train you in application of the dot rule (which is simple: mutual inductance e.m.f. has the same sign as self inductance e.m.f. when both the loop current and the coupled current are flowing in or out of dotted ends; the signs are opposite otherwise); you have to apply it 4 times for your second loop.

You did it well with the first loop.

Physically you have a transformer with two secondary windings, connected in opposite directions. Voltage from the one winding cancels voltage from the other, so the second loop has no current.